# Using the OpenVR library from C FFI

Tags: c, swig, ffi, steamworks-api, openvr

I'm trying to use the openVR library from another language which only has ffi support for C.

I saw that there is a C header with the following comment: "Purpose: Header for flatted SteamAPI. Use this for binding to other languages."

Any idea how to use it ?

Thanks for the explanations

Comment: I saw that LibOVR also has a C API

Comment: It depends heavily on the "another language", which is?